# UEFI strange behavior - works once but deletes MBR

Tags: boot, grub, uefi

I have a Toshiba Satellite L50-A1-D6 with the latest (14 November 2014) BIOS update.
I have removed Windows 8, completely formatted the HDD (in GPT),
and installed Linux (Ubuntu, but this is not really important).

If I keep my laptop in UEFI mode it acts weirdly:

- The laptop boots correctly into Linux, but when I shutdown, it refuses
  to boot again (at boot it shows a "no bootable media found" error).
- So I booted up from a live USB, reinstalled GRUB and I can boot the
  computer normally -- but just ONCE!

Actually, before shutting down my computer I have to reinstall GRUB in the "fake MBR" every time! If I reinstall everything goes well... If I forget to reinstall, the computer refuses to boot.

It seems that my computer erases the fake MBR every time I boot.

Is there a solution? A workaround or similar?

Comment: in my bios it has two options for the boot device order: bios decided or OS decided. If yours points to OS decided, and it can't find the original OS, this could make it say no bootable media.

Comment: In this case the OS is installed and booted the right way, in fact the os boot... just only once!

Comment: so, how is your bootloader setup? Grub on the MBR which points to the windows loader?

Comment: I have removed windows completely as I described before

Comment: ah, ok. so what if you don't keep it "in UEFI mode"

Comment: If I don't keep it in UEFI mode the actual OS doesn't boot anymore.
But probabily it will work if I repartition the disk in MBR.
The question here is "whats happening in this UEFI"

Comment: ok, but i still don't understand what you mean by "fake mbr" what would the "real mbr" be?

Comment: As I understood (maybe wrong) every GPT partition table has a "fake MBR" header, so it's understandable (as possible) from old PC as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know you won't like this, but, firstly, I would go to the manufacturers website to see if there is any update available to the BIOS/EFI.

I have not seen this in ages, but I remember seeing it quite a bit around the time Windows 8 generation boards/laptops launched - It could be that your bootable usb stick is fully compatible but after the first boot, your machine is attempting to regenerate secure key certificates or similar and failing.... When I last saw this error, I removed Secure Boot and everything worked as expected.

If all else fails, a workaround I would do is to make a usb stick and install Grub with a default option of boot from hard drive and try to make that the default boot device and just leave it in... Not pretty, but as long as your machine supports booting from USB as the primary option, it could be a good work around.

Comment: This was my first thought too... I found an update on the toshiba website, installed it (as i specified in the question) but nothing changed, neither in the UI of the BIOS nor in the functionality.